# Nested Form Not Passing Id Attribute on Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameter-passing, nested-forms, fields-for

I am using rails5 nested form and 
my nested form is like below

**permitted params**

```
params.require(:audit_type).permit(:name, :total_score, :id,
      risk_scoring_attributes: [:low, :medium, :high, :zero_tolerance, :_destroy, :id],
      audit_ratings_attributes: [ :id, :from, :to, :description, :_destroy])
```

**View**

```
    <%= nested_form_for(@audit_type, method: :patch) do |f| %>
            <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-search table-striped table-responsive" id="condensedTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Result</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id='audit_rating_data'>
              <%= f.fields_for :audit_ratings, @audit_type.audit_ratings, :wrapper => false do |builder| %>
                <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even") -%> number-cell fields">
                  <td class="v-align-middle semi-bold">
                    <%= builder.number_field :from, placeholder: "#", class: 'from_field', required: true %>
                  </td>
                  <td class="v-align-middle">
                    <%= builder.number_field :to, placeholder: "#", class: 'to_field', required: true %>
                  </td>
                  <td class="v-align-middle semi-bold">
                  <%= builder.text_area :description, class: "text-uppercase", required: true %>
                  </td>
                  <td class="v-align-middle">
                  <%= builder.link_to_remove "<i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>".html_safe, class: "btn btn-rounded btn-danger" %>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <%= f.link_to_add "<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>".html_safe, :audit_ratings, class: "btn btn-rounded btn-primary", :data => { :target => "#audit_rating_data" }  %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

and in model have relation

```
  has_many :audit_ratings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :audit_ratings, allow_destroy: true
```

while updating if i delete any associated records it passing parameters as

```
"audit_ratings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"from"=>"10", "to"=>"20", "description"=>"test", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1"=>{"from"=>"10", "to"=>"20", "description"=>"test", "_destroy"=>"1"} }
```

what i observed is it missing id attribute on update, actually it comes as a hidden field for Nested form. so its creating new record rather than delete.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your strong params from the controller?

Comment: updated the code, verify once

Comment: Where are you sending `id` to the conroller? There's no `hidden_field` for it in your  view, like you mention in your question.

Comment: Add complete form code or you can just add a hidden field in builder `fields_for` section to do it like : `<%= builder.hidden_field :id, builder.id %>`

Comment: i am using has_one also nested for same form it is rendering id, _destroy fields through nested_form gem but its not happening in has_many relation

Comment: @muhammad getting undefined method `id' for #<NestedForm::Builder:0x007f00eed58d38>

Comment: oh, this should be like `builder.object.id` for value.

Comment: <%= builder.hidden_field :id, builder.object.id %>, raising (undefined method `merge' for 2:Fixnum)

Comment: I think you want `<%= builder.hidden_field :id, value: builder.object.id %>`

Comment: Thank you Anthony and muhammad, working fine, if you post answer i could accept answer, but i didn't understand this unexpected behaviour from gem

Answer (score 1):

Solution will be to add a hidden field for `id` for `audit_ratings` fields_for like :

```
<%= builder.hidden_field :id, :value => builder.object.id %>
```